# How to get BAYEUX_BROWSER cookie from cometd.NET client

Tags: .net, cookies, client, cometd

I am using cometd.net client, server side uses cometd java. 
After handshake, server will return a json payload, in response header, there is
Set-Cookie: BAYEUX_BROWSER=533bkb4ydvb9rti9gz9zxs3fgfv, how to get this from client? 
I saw there is clientid in json payload, but that's not bayeux_broswer.  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. It is in LongPollingTransport.GetResponseCallback, 
add cookie from response to LongPollingTransport.parent