# Setting Cookie Domain in CometD

Tags: c#, .net, salesforce, cometd, cometd.net

CometD .NET is throwing an exception when calling the `setCookie(string, string)` method on `BayeuxClient` because I haven't set a domain for these cookies, but I don't see a property or method to set the domain, and none of the overloads on `setCookie(...)` take a domain as a parameter.

Code:

```
this._bayeuxClient = new BayeuxClient(
                "https://***.salesforce.com/cometd/24.0", //instance omitted
                new List<ClientTransport> { new LongPollingTransport(null) });

this._bayeuxClient.setCookie("com.salesforce.LocaleInfo", "us");
//...

this._bayeuxClient.handshake(); //Exception is thrown here.
this._bayeuxClient.waitFor(1000, 
    new List<BayeuxClient.State> { BayeuxClient.State.CONNECTED });
```

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519910/how-to-get-bayeux-browser-cookie-from-cometd-net-client ?

Comment: @RyanGuest, I believe that post is about cookies in the server's response. I'm trying to add cookies to the request.

Comment: @lukiffer, did you ever complete your integration with Salesforce? I'm attempting to do the same thing and I'm stuck http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337723/how-do-you-add-an-authorization-header-using-cometd-net

Comment: @Vyrotek, we abandoned the integration and reverted to the SOAP API. We were however successful with the streaming API, but had to implement everything ourselves using `WebClient`